# Extend BottomSheetDialogFragment from a class instantiated in a fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, modal-dialog, android-context

I have a fragment (FragmentSearchResults) that contains results retrieved from a database, in which there is a button "filters". When the user taps on such a button, a class (FiltersDialog) extending a BottomSheetDialogFragment is instantiated, so that the user can set his filters. When the user closes the FiltersDialog activity, the values are passed from FiltersDialog to FragmentSearchResults.

```
    public class FragmentSearchResults extends Fragment implements FiltersDialog.FilterListener {

        /* code */

        ImageButton btnFilter = myFragment.findViewById(R.id.btn_filters);
        btnFilter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showFilters();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showFilters() {
        FiltersDialog filtersDialog = new FiltersDialog();
        filtersDialog.show(((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), "argument");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NotNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFiltersSet(Map filters) {
        // apply filters selected by user
    }

    public interface FilterListener {
        void onFiltersSet(Map filters);
    }
}



public class FiltersDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private FilterListener mListener;
    private Map<String, Object> mFilters;

    public FiltersDialog() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_filters_dialog, container, false);

        TextView txtSave = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_save_filters);

        mTxtSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onFiltersSet(mFilters);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public interface FilterListener {
        void onFiltersSet(Map filters);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NotNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (context instanceof FilterListener) {
            mListener = (FilterListener) context;
        }
        else {
            // Here's the error, as the activity Home.java containing FragmentSearchResults
            // does not implement FilterListener, FragmentSearchResults does
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement FilterListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that FilterListener needs to be implemented in FragmentSearchResults, but I am passing the activity Home context.

How can I implement FilterListener in the fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create method inside your `FiltersDialog`, like

```
public void setFiltersListener(FiltersDialog.FilterListener listener) {
   mListener = listener;
}
```

and simply call it after you instantiate the dialog.

```
FiltersDialog filtersDialog = new FiltersDialog();
filtersDialog.setFiltersListener(this);
filtersDialog.show(((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), "argument");
```

Then you can use the listener inside dialog. something like this

```
if (mListener != null) {
    mListener.onFiltersSet(mFilters);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I setup `listener` to the dialog?

parameter of `onAttach` in `Fragment` is **FragmentHost(Activity).** thus, it can't typecast to `FilterListener`.

I suggest a simple way to implement `FilterListener` setter in `FragmentDialog` as below code.

```java
... in FiltersDialog
public void setListener(FilterListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
...

... in FragmentSearchResults
private void showFilters() {
    FiltersDialog filtersDialog = new FiltersDialog();
    filtersDialog.setListener(this);
    filtersDialog.show(((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), "argument");
}
...
//When FragmentSearchResults recreated, FiltersDialog must also need to be recreated.
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach will be to use LiveData, ViewModel in this case. Use Shared ViewModel Approach, An Activity Level ViewModel can be accessed via all the fragments lying in its environment.

- Make an Activity Level ViewModel
- Define a LiveData in ViewModel
- When your "FragmentSearchResults" opens for the first time, start
  observing it.
- When You open "FiltersDialog" screen and click save button, Then post
  to LiveData changes in the filter (You have activity context    here,
  You can fetch ActivityViewModel here, get LiveData from it,    post
  changes to this LiveData)
- Now As "FragmentSearchResults" is already observing changes in the
  LiveData, You will get callback here, make changes accordingly. This way your code will be completely decoupled. You will be escaped from
  hustles of Interfaces.